# Random Partitions Show Up-I Didn't Create Any

Tags: partitioning, gnome, python3

[The Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkgO1.png)

Essentially what happened is that I purged python3 and reinstalled it. That's literally all that happened.

Along with the weird partitions, terminal, Firefox, and Gnome Software uninstalled themselves. (I've manually reinstalled them, so that's ok now)

What's going on with this?

Comment: See if any of those partitions match the output of `df -h`. You might be looking at Snap mounts. Or perhaps you are looking at something else. It's quite possible "all that happened" is you damaged your system extensively by purging Python3. The full story depends upon details of exactly what you did that you have not provided.

Comment: Sometimes when you uninstall a program, it uninstalls dependencies.  And sometimes these dependencies include programs that we don't want uninstalled.  Of course, I find it strange that `Firefox` depends on `python3`...but any way, I wouldn't worry about programs "uninstalling themselves", provided you did something to initiate it (i.e., by uninstalling a program).  Just install it back.  And yes, we do need more information to help you, but (so far) it doesn't seem to be anything worth worrying about.